# Python and OpenCV: convert 16 bit image to gray image

Tags: python, opencv

I have a 16 bit image and I would like to convert it into gray.

With 8 bit images it works fine with:

```
img = cv2.imread('test.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(gray, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

People here in stackoverflow write that OpenCV doesn't work that good with more than 8 bit images ?

Does anyone know a possibility to convert my 16 bit .png image to gray?

Comment: You have to think what it is represented with this 16 bit... is it depth image? is it thermal image? is it just a fancy greyscale? you can always use `normalize(img, dst, 0,255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8U)` if you only want a grey image.... also, depending on the functions opencv may accept 16 bits... so it depends on what is the image and what you want to do with it

Comment: I want to measure pixel intensities in a grayscale depth image (monochrom laser measuring). And it must be 16bit after converting, because it must be very accurate.

Comment: have you tried this `COLOR_BGR5652GRAY `. I think you will get more ideas [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html).

Comment: I tried ´COLOR_BGR5652GRAY´ and got cv2.error: /home/...: error: (-215) scn == 2 && depth == CV_8U in function cvtColor

Comment: You are saying that you already have a grayscale image, you don't need to convert, just normalize. Although, if you want it in 8bit you will lose information. Try `img.astype(np.uint8)` it should work if `img` type is `np.uint16`.

Comment: @Anja so if it is a depth image, the values are important, and should not be changed to 8 bits... if you want to display it, then you can convert a copy, but use the 16 bits one for other functions... check the documentation first to see which type of matrix is supported sometimes you may need to change it to double or float to avoid loosing accuracy

Comment: thank you! It works with img.astype(np.uint16) and to check the documentation first is a very good hint ;)

Comment: @Anja... post your last comment as self-answer. That is aloud to do so. Select as best answer because you taught yourself (with obvious help from others). What happens is that this question is seen as answered and gets removed from question-queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with 
`img.astype(np.uint16)`
and to check the documentation first is a very good hint!